# Aggregate by month,day of week hour and min in R

Tags: r, datetime, aggregation, xts

I have a folder with several files where the name of each file is the respective userID. Something like this:

```
         Time           Sms
 1 2012-01-01 00:00:00  10
 2 2012-01-01 00:30:00  11
 3 2012-01-01 01:00:00  13
 4 2012-01-01 01:30:00  10
```

How can i aggretate by moth, week, hour and minute? Something like this:

```
Month DayofWeek hour min  SMS
 1      Mon      0    0   14   <-mean 
 1      Mon      0   30   12
 1      Mon      1    0   17
 1      Mon      1   30   21
 .............................
 12    Sunday    23  30   12
```

Comment: If you want to aggregate different years separately, you may also want to consider using built in xts functionality if you're working with xts objects.  Look at `?period.apply`

Comment: I do not need the years. I just want to calculate the average for for every second, tuesday ..etc of January, February, .... to hour x and minute y. 
     Something like this: January, Monday, 00:00 <- is the average of all values of years in which January (id = 1), dayofweek (id = 1), hour (h = 0) and minute (min = 0 )

Comment: @FXQuantTrader i look at `?period.apply` but I can only use one argument to aggregate such as year or month, I wanted a table like the one mentioned above.

Comment: you can aggregate to k second intervals with period.apply.  But as you don' t want to split by year, it makes sense to convert to a data.table/frame and aggregate as the other answers suggest.  xts objects aggregate as time series and won't be suitable for grouping by month alone across years... (hence why I asked if you if you want to split by year or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help. I solved my problem by applying this code:

```
df<-aggregate(Sms~month(Time)+weekdays(Time)+hour(Time)+minute(Time),df,FUN='mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue aggregating hourly data into daily data. This is the code that worked for me.

```
fun <- function(s,i,j) { sum(s[i:(i+j-1)]) }

radday<-sapply(X=seq(1,24*nb_of_days,24),FUN=fun,s=your_time_series,j=24)
```

This sums data across a period `j`, which in my case since I was summing over 24 hours was 24. By changing the `j` value you can adjust it for your different periods of hour, day, week, month assuming that you have a constant period.